# All pages return the same content with OVH Cloud Hosting

Tags: node.js, express

I've recently completed a Node.js website locally, which works fine, though I have noticed some issues when uploading the website online to OVH Cloud Web Hosting. All pages, even those that should not exist, return the contents of the homepage.

I'm running Express with Node.js, and the file structure was created with [express-generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html). My `app.js` file contains the following:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressHbs = require('express-handlebars');
var Handlebars     = require('handlebars');
var HandlebarsIntl = require('handlebars-intl');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var blogRouter = require('./routes/blog');
var blogItemRouter = require('./routes/blog-item');
var portfolioRouter = require('./routes/portfolio');
var contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');
var iBlogPostsRouter = require('./routes/i/blog-posts');
var iContactRouter = require('./routes/i/contact');
var iPortfolioItemsRouter = require('./routes/i/portfolio-items');
var portfolioItemRouter = require('./routes/portfolio-item');

HandlebarsIntl.registerWith(Handlebars);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
app.disable('etag');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/blog', blogRouter);
app.use('/blog/:title', blogItemRouter);
app.use('/portfolio', portfolioRouter);
app.use('/contact', contactRouter);
app.use('/i/blog-posts', iBlogPostsRouter);
app.use('/i/contact', iContactRouter);
app.use('/i/portfolio-items', iPortfolioItemsRouter);
app.use('/portfolio/:title', portfolioItemRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {title: err.status + ' ' + err.message});
});
```

module.exports = app;

All of the routers have the same code, except render a different template. Here is an example of the `indexRouter`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'About', about: true });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The issue is that every page, even my `.js` and `.css` files, returns the HTML from whatever is in the `app.use('/' ...)` router. The console returns the following error:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://xxx.co.uk/core/styles/m.css".
```

I experimented with this by changing the homepage to be my contact page, which has resulted in every URL returning the contact page. My CSS and JavaScript are in a `public` folder. The only thing that I can think of is that the '/' route is somehow being used for every single request, but it doesn't make any sense to me why this could be happening.

Comment: how did you upload this? How did you start the server(npm process) on the cloud?

Comment: This was uploaded via FTP to their servers, and set up to run. I don't have control of the NPM process; I just upload the files.

Comment: your node server probably isn't running. You see the same page each time because probably on the cloud your app is being treated as static website, `public/index.html` is returned. Is your hosting Node.js based? or a simple server?

Comment: It was running on a Node.js environment with OVH Cloud Hosting. I've since cancelled the hosting, set up a VPS, deployed the exact same code as above and the website worked fine.

Comment: I guess your nodejs server was indeed not running then. Do you mind if I add that as an answer?

Comment: Node.js _was_ running on the server, as the app.js file was being read and used to determine the '/' route. Changing the '/' route would modify every single page on the website to be whatever was connected to that route. I'm just unsure of why it decided that every path was just '/'.

Comment: Can you please share the code of another router file, so it will help us debug.

Comment: Also, try changing the following line in your code `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` to `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: Hi @Arihant, thanks for the response! Unfortunately I'm not using their hosting service any more and have since moved to a VPS, which I have had no issues in using the original code with (meaning I can't test this any more). I'm hoping to delete the question once the bounty ends.

Comment: Cool @ReesMorris .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `app.use('/<route>', <router>)` in your project, try replacing it with the corresponding express statements, e.g,

```
router.<route_method>('/<route>', function(req, res, next){
  // code
});
```

See if it works fine or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this and it looks like every page now returns the 404 page HTML, even things in the `public` directory such as the stylesheet and the JavaScript.

Comment: Seems as though changing `router` to `app` fixed this, though the same issue as in the original post still persists.

Comment: you might have done something wrong, if you would share your implementation then it will be more clearer.

Comment: You can try the above method and provide me the implementation and I'll let you know how your 404 issue can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your site is defaulting to the '/' route is because you haven't properly set up your routes. Each router module needs to know what is getting exported. Your `indexRouter` file, for example, needs to look like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router;

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'About', about: true });
});

module.exports = router;   <<----
```

In addition, if the `app.js` you're showing as of 09/04/2018 06:36 is the *complete* `app.js`, you're missing a lot. You have a minimized CSS as your first stylesheet, which actually contains the rendered `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I didn't include the entire app.js, though that's an oversight on my part. I've edited the post to include the full files for both `app.js` (excluding the database connection and locals) and `indexRouter.js`.

In terms of the stylesheet, every URL on the page (even if it should be 404) also returns the index.html file.

Comment: Yes, because, if you use the developer tools in your browser to view your site, you will see three CSS link tags in the <head>--the first one having a unreadable name. View that first file in your Sources tabs and you will see a rendered version of your index.html. Check your index view.